# MEANJS check if for null on findOne

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meanjs

I'm just starting off with MEANJS. I am tinkering with the sample Articles module.

Looking at the code for findOne(), it seems to query the db then return it and assign to `$scope.article`.

```
    // Find existing Article
    $scope.findOne = function() {
        $scope.article = Articles.get({
            articleId: $stateParams.articleId
        });
    };
```

I would like it to so something else like redirect or show a 404 if it returns nothing. Maybe because had a typo on the URL. I started to test to see what kind of results by purposely putting in bad IDs on the URL.

**Results**

- When ID was actually present, in console, I would see "found something" followed by 'undefined'.
- When ID was bad, in console, I would see "found something" followed by 'underfined' THEN followed by a 400 'Bad Request' error.

  ```
  // Find existing Article
  $scope.findOne = function() {
      $scope.article = Articles.get({
          articleId: $stateParams.articleId
      });
      if ($scope.article) {
          console.log('found something');
          console.log($scope.article._id);
      }
      else    {
          console.log('found NOTHING');
      }
  };
  ```

Bottom line is, how do I check if I am actually getting something or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the **`Articles.get()`** function is asynchronous, it should return a **[`$promise`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)** object which you can then check for the objects returned. Something like this should work:

```
var self = this;
Articles.get({
    articleId: $stateParams.articleId
}).$promise.then(function(data){
    if (data) {
    console.log('found something');
    console.log(data.article._id);
    self.article = data.article;
}
else {
    console.log('found NOTHING');
});
```